# Getting current URL of Internet Explorer 8 programatically

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, internet-explorer-8

I'm developing a simple Internet Explorer add-on and I'm trying to get the current URL of the Address Bar of the IE 8 using the series of (example) `HWND handle = FindWindowEx(parent_handle,0,"AddressDisplay Control",NULL);`

in the following order:

```
1- IEFrame
2- WorkerW
3- ReBarWindow32
4- Address Band Root
5- Edit 
5- (alternatively) AddressDisplay Control
```

I've determined this series of controls using the winspy++ 1.6

The code I'm trying to get the current URL is:

```
TCHAR currentURL[255];
::GetWindowText(handle_to_the_Edit_or_AddressDisplay_control, currentURL, 255);
```

However it sets nothing into the currentURL array.

This method, with the names and series of controls slightly changed, used to work in earlier versions ıf IE, I could easliy get the current URL,  but for IE 8  I've unable to get it.

What should I do? Thanks

Note: I've searched many pages and posts. No luck.

Comment: I smell malware. Hope you have AV solution installed during development. :P

Comment: The problem is not related to any security issues. It's just a programming exercise.

Comment: See OldNewThing blog: "[A big little program: Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows, part 1: Enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130610-00/?p=4133)"

Comment: @zett42 thank you for the suggestion. That is a proper way to get URL in IE but it uses the COM/ATL stack and therefore not so practical. I've tried adding the GetBrowserInfo function in the article but one of the required header files `atlalloc.h` was unavailable on my VC++ 6 and VC++2010 Express environment.

Comment: What kind of add-on exactly?  If it is a BHO (Browser Helper Object) then it has direct access to the browser's `IWebBrowser2` interface and can simply query that for its current URL within having to resort to accessing the UI controls at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau 
It pulls the current URL and manipulates some part of it for ease of navigation; so it's a BHO. I've given a try to the `IWebBrowser2`'s `get_LocationURL` property (or method?) like this:
`char strCurURL[255];`
`HRESULT temp = m_pBrowser->get_LocationURL((BSTR*) strCurURL);`
`::SendMessage(hMyEditControl,WM_SETTEXT,0,(long)strCurURL);`
But the `strCurURL` appears incorrectly. How to arrange it? `hMyEditControl` is a normal Edit control.

Comment: @Romario you can't typecast a `TCHAR[]` buffer into a `BSTR*` like that. `get_LocationURL()` allocates and returns a new `BSTR`, you need to *copy/convert* that string into your buffer as needed and then free the `BSTR` when done. `BSTR bstrURL; HRESULT temp = m_pBrowser->get_LocationURL(&bstrURL); /* use bstrURL as needed ... */ SysFreeString(bstrURL);` If your Edit control is a Unicode window, you don't even need the buffer at all: `BSTR bstrURL; HRESULT temp = m_pBrowser->get_LocationURL(&bstrURL); SendMessage(hMyEditControl, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)bstrURL); SysFreeString(bstrURL);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau 
That kind of conversion: `char *p = _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(bstrURL);` solved the problem `::SendMessage(hMyEditControl,WM_SETTEXT,0,(long)p);` now displays correctly. That counts as an accepted answer too, so thank you but could you still comment more on the reasons why one cannot get this URL from the UI controls? Particularly when it's possible to do it on IE 7?

Comment: @Romario Because that is not the right way to do it, even in IE7.  Just because it *could* be done that way does not mean it *should* be done that way. There is a reason why a BHO has direct access to the underlying WebBrowser object, the BHO should not rely on any particular UI representation of the WebBrowser object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying @Remy Lebeau's suggestion `char *p = _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(bstrURL);` , `::SendMessage(hMyEditControl,WM_SETTEXT,0,(long)p);` started to display correctly.

And this explains why the IE 7 way of getting the URL from the UI controls doesn't work on IE 8:

```
Because that is not the right way to do it, even in IE7. 
Just because it could be done that way does not mean it should be done that way.
There is a reason why a BHO has direct access to the underlying WebBrowser object,
the BHO should not rely on any particular UI representation of the WebBrowser object.
```

So that's the accepted answer.